# Error when #include <chrono> in c++14/c++17

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-errors, c++-chrono

I'm trying to include `chrono` in my project and need support of `c++14`.

But when I compile it in `c++14/c++17`, errors occurred.

Code:

```cpp
#include<chrono>
int main(){return 0;}
```

Compile it:

```
gcc test.cc -lstdc++ -std=c++14
```

Error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/chrono:38,
                 from test.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:51:50: error: expected template-name before ‘<’ token
   51 |     struct _Digit<_Base, '0'> : integral_constant<unsigned, 0>
      |                                                  ^
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:51:50: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘<’ token
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:57:50: error: expected template-name before ‘<’ token
   57 |     struct _Digit<_Base, '1'> : integral_constant<unsigned, 1>
      |                                                  ^
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:57:50: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘<’ token
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:63:43: error: expected template-name before ‘<’ token
   63 |     struct _Digit_impl : integral_constant<unsigned, _Val>
      |                                           ^
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:63:43: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘<’ token
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:151:51: error: expected template-name before ‘<’ token
  151 |     struct _Digit<_Base, '\''> : integral_constant<unsigned, 0>
      |                                                   ^
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:151:51: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘<’ token
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:159:28: error: ‘integral_constant’ does not name a type
  159 |     using __ull_constant = integral_constant<unsigned long long, _Val>;
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:167:4: error: ‘__ull_constant’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘__builtin_constant_p’?
  167 |  = __ull_constant<__next::value * (__valid_digit{} ? _Base : 1ULL)>;
      |    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |    __builtin_constant_p
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:167:52: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘?’ token
  167 |  = __ull_constant<__next::value * (__valid_digit{} ? _Base : 1ULL)>;
      |                                                    ^
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:174:20: error: ‘__ull_constant’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘__builtin_constant_p’?
  174 |       using type = __ull_constant<__valid_digit::value>;
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                    __builtin_constant_p
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:182:42: error: expected template-name before ‘<’ token
  182 |     struct _Power<_Base> : __ull_constant<0>
      |                                          ^
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:182:42: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘<’ token
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:195:20: error: ‘__ull_constant’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘__builtin_constant_p’?
  195 |       using type = __ull_constant<_Pow * __digit::value + __next::type::value>;
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                    __builtin_constant_p
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:196:22: error: ‘type’ has not been declared
  196 |       static_assert((type::value / _Pow) == __digit::value,
      |                      ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:210:20: error: ‘__ull_constant’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘__builtin_constant_p’?
  210 |       using type = __ull_constant<_Digit<_Base, _Dig>::value>;
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                    __builtin_constant_p
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:220:21: error: expected template-name before ‘<’ token
  220 |     : __ull_constant<0>
      |                     ^
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:220:21: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘<’ token
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:268:20: error: expected template-name before ‘<’ token
  268 |     : conditional_t<(_Val <= std::numeric_limits<_IntType>::max()),
      |                    ^
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:268:20: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘<’ token
@root ➜ proof_of_work git(master)  gcc test.cc -lstdc++ -std=c++14
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/chrono:38,
                 from test.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:51:50: error: expected template-name before ‘<’ token
   51 |     struct _Digit<_Base, '0'> : integral_constant<unsigned, 0>
      |                                                  ^
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:51:50: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘<’ token
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:57:50: error: expected template-name before ‘<’ token
   57 |     struct _Digit<_Base, '1'> : integral_constant<unsigned, 1>
      |                                                  ^
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:57:50: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘<’ token
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:63:43: error: expected template-name before ‘<’ token
   63 |     struct _Digit_impl : integral_constant<unsigned, _Val>
      |                                           ^
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:63:43: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘<’ token
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:151:51: error: expected template-name before ‘<’ token
  151 |     struct _Digit<_Base, '\''> : integral_constant<unsigned, 0>
      |                                                   ^
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:151:51: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘<’ token
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:159:28: error: ‘integral_constant’ does not name a type
  159 |     using __ull_constant = integral_constant<unsigned long long, _Val>;
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:167:4: error: ‘__ull_constant’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘__builtin_constant_p’?
  167 |  = __ull_constant<__next::value * (__valid_digit{} ? _Base : 1ULL)>;
      |    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |    __builtin_constant_p
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:167:52: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘?’ token
  167 |  = __ull_constant<__next::value * (__valid_digit{} ? _Base : 1ULL)>;
      |                                                    ^
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:174:20: error: ‘__ull_constant’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘__builtin_constant_p’?
  174 |       using type = __ull_constant<__valid_digit::value>;
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                    __builtin_constant_p
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:182:42: error: expected template-name before ‘<’ token
  182 |     struct _Power<_Base> : __ull_constant<0>
      |                                          ^
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:182:42: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘<’ token
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:195:20: error: ‘__ull_constant’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘__builtin_constant_p’?
  195 |       using type = __ull_constant<_Pow * __digit::value + __next::type::value>;
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                    __builtin_constant_p
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:196:22: error: ‘type’ has not been declared
  196 |       static_assert((type::value / _Pow) == __digit::value,
      |                      ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:210:20: error: ‘__ull_constant’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘__builtin_constant_p’?
  210 |       using type = __ull_constant<_Digit<_Base, _Dig>::value>;
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                    __builtin_constant_p
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:220:21: error: expected template-name before ‘<’ token
  220 |     : __ull_constant<0>
      |                     ^
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:220:21: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘<’ token
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:268:20: error: expected template-name before ‘<’ token
  268 |     : conditional_t<(_Val <= std::numeric_limits<_IntType>::max()),
      |                    ^
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/parse_numbers.h:268:20: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘<’ token
```

Besides:

- no error when using `c++11`.
- use clang++ also has same problem
- I compile it on **wsl**(ubuntu 20.04)

So how to fix it?

Comment: So the compiler does not appear to know what some pretty basic things like, for example, what `std::integral_constant` is.  The `std::integral_constant` template is defined in the header `<type_traits>`.    Now I admit I would expect that if the `<chrono>` header requires `std::integral_constant`, then it would include `<type_traits>` on its own.  But regardless you might try explicitly including it before you include `<chrono>`   In the very least, that might change the error message you get and teach you something more about the actual problem.

Comment: (I think) Not the cause, but using `gcc` instead of `g++` to compile a C++ program is the wrong approach. You should also not explicitly link `stdc++`. `g++` will handle all of that for you.

Comment: Also check the contents of the `/usr/include/c++/9/chrono` file. It should include `<type_traits>` before `parse_numbers.h` and looking at the repo mirror on github I can't find any GCC 9 version where `parse_numbers.h` is included at line `38`. It should be line `42` (e.g. https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/releases/gcc-9.5.0/libstdc++-v3/include/std/chrono#L42).

Comment: Thanks. I work it out by include `<type_traits>` before `<bits/parse_numbers.h>` in chrono, my gcc version is 9.4.0.

Comment: I think the reason why `<type_traits>` is include before `<bits/parse_numbers.h>` is that my vscode do something to rearrange header files when I `ctrl+S`......

Comment: you should not be including anything from bits in your own code

Comment: @phanen So it seems like you accidentally modified the system headers. You are not supposed to do that at all, nor should you be including anything from `bits` manually. Remove and reinstall GCC so that header files are reset to what they are supposed to be and make sure that you run your IDE as a non-root user, so that you are not able to accidentally edit them again.